# Building an app for L that is back compatible to ICS

Tags: gradle, android-5.0-lollipop, android-productflavors

So yesterday I downloaded the source of the Google I/O Android App, that has a version that runs on L and is also back compatible to ICS. While browsing the code I noticed that everything specific to L was put in a separate productFlavor (see [this user guide if you need more information about productFlavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)). Because I am new with Android Studio and gradle, I want to know is this the right and proper solution when developing an app that is targeted at L, but wants to be back compatible down to ICS versions..?
I will start the development of an app that fits these requirements and probably won't be released until L is fully revealed, so to waste no time I want to start building the basics and just want to know is this the right way to go...?

P.S Do I need to define productFalvors and with that have different apk-s for the corresponding flavors, or can I still divide my logic in java (as I did till now) and have one apk that works everywhere... What is best and why?

Comment: It really depends on the amount of new Android-5 features you are using. There is no definitive absolute answer to this question. Just an advice : don't do useless work. i.e. don't create flavor before you really see the need to create them.